# Suggestion for parsing values from a particular format

Tags: c

I'm working on a client-server program, where initial step involves parsing the request from client on the server side. The input would look like this.
INSERT A->B B->C; QUERY A B; RESET;
So there are three different commands and they are separated by ';'. RESET option has no parameters. INSERT might have any number of parameter(which are space separated and each value separated by "->"). QUERY is again space separated. The server has to build a acyclic graph based on the input. So my problem is to parse this string into subsequent requests. I planned on using 'strtok' and when the final value is reached(for example 'A'), create a linked list of INSERTS(since the number of request is unknown). But my code is too big and I'm looking for a more concise solution for this problem.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct insert {
    char event1;
    char event2;
    struct insert * next;
}insert,*insPtr;

typedef struct query {
    char event1;
    char event2;
    struct query * next;
}query,*queryPtr;

typedef struct reset {
     int status;
 }reset,*rPtr;

 void create_node(char *events) {
     char event[2];
     char *a,*str;
     char *pch = strtok(events,"->");
     while(pch != NULL) {
         printf("%s\n",pch);
         pch = strtok(NULL,"->");
     }
}

int insert_parser(char *string) {

char *a, *b;
a =  string;
b = "INSERT ";
while(*a == *b){
    a++;
    b++;
} 

char *pch = strtok(a," ");
while(pch){
    printf("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok(NULL," ");
}
return(0);
}

int parse_for_values (char* command) {
    int value;
    if (strstr(command, "INSERT") !=NULL ) {
        printf("%s\n",command);
        printf ("Insert command found\n");
        value = 1;
    } else if(strstr(command, "QUERY") !=NULL) {
        printf("%s\n",command);
        printf ("Query command found\n");
        value = 2;
    } else if(strstr(command, "RESET") != NULL) {
        printf ("Reset command found\n");
        printf("%s\n",command);
        value = 3;
    } else {
        printf("unknown command:%s:\n",command);
        printf("Unknown command\n");
        return(1);
    }
    switch(value) {
        case 1:
            insert_parser(command);         
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        case 3:
            break;

    }
    return(0);
}

int parse_for_command(char *input) {
    char *ptr;
    input = strtok(input,"\n");// this strtok is to remove the trailing '\n' in the string
    ptr = strtok(input,";");
   //   printf("%s\n",ptr); 
    char *cmdPtr;
    while(ptr != NULL) {
        cmdPtr = ptr;
        parse_for_values(cmdPtr);
//      printf("%s",ptr);
        ptr = strtok(NULL, ";"); //NULL as first argument tells strtok to work on internally held value
    }
    return(0);
}


int main() {
    char input[100];
    printf("Enter the input\n");
    fgets(input, 100, stdin);
    //printf("%s",input); 
    char *inp = input;
    inp = strtok(inp,"\n");
    create_node(inp);
    //parser(input,"INSERT ", "->");            
    //parse_for_command(input);
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to find individual tokens ([lexical analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis)) and analyse this sequence of tokens ([syntactic analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing)). Either you write these procedures manually, or you formally specify syntax of your language and employ existing tools to create the required C code automatically (see [flex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_lexical_analyser) and [bison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_bison)).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on what you are asking, but the separation of the input commands into individual strings can be done with a single set of calls to `strtok`. Additionally, the time to remove the trailing newline resulting from the call to `fgets` is immediately after the call to `fgets` so you do not have dangling newlines hanging off the end of the string. (e.g.):

```
fgets(input, 100, stdin);
len = strlen (input);                     /* get length of str        */
if (input[len - 1] != '\n')               /* no '\n', input too long  */
    input[--len] = 0;                     /* null-terminate           */
```

Separating the strings with `strtok` can make use of a `for` loop to handle the initial and subsequent calls to `NULL` in a single call. For purposes of the example, I've just used a statically declared character array to hold the separated strings, but you can just as well pass `p` to whatever type list or abstraction you desire. If your intent was to further separate the individual components of each command, then a simple while loop walking a pointer (or two) down the separated `INSERT` or `QUERY` command will work. Below is the example, if your intent was different, please let me know.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NCMD 10
#define LCMD 64

int main (void) {

    char input[] = "INSERT A->B B->C; QUERY A B; RESET;";
    char command[NCMD][LCMD] = {{0}};
    char *p = NULL;
    size_t i = 0;
    size_t ncmd = 0;

    for (p = strtok (input, ";"); p; p = strtok (NULL, ";")) {
        while (*p == ' ') p++;
        strncpy (command[ncmd++], p, LCMD);
    }

    printf ("\n The separated commands are:\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < ncmd; i++)
        printf ("   command[%zu] : %s\n", i, command[i]);
    printf ("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/parseinput

 The separated commands are:

   command[0] : INSERT A->B B->C
   command[1] : QUERY A B
   command[2] : RESET
```

**Note:** the length validation on `p` as well as the limit check on `ncmd` were intentionally omitted for purposes of the example.